# Is return value optimization dependable in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

As this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) page says (code exerted as below), return value optimization is an allowed by C++ compiler, but still depends on the implementation. To reduce the cost of copying, is it recommended to do optimize it manually (assign the object of function to a reference, like `const C& obj = f();`) or leave the compiler to do such optimization in practice?

```
#include <iostream>

struct C {
  C() {}
  C(const C&) { std::cout << "A copy was made.\n"; }
};

C f() {
  return C();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  C obj = f();
}
```

EDIT: Update the change as const reference.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. `C& obj = f()` does not do the optimisation manually. It won't even compile.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The changed version compiles in VS2013, do you mean it has incorrect semantics?

Comment: @Thomson: That compiler is notorious for allowing "extensions" like that. Your code won't be portable if you rely on them.

Comment: @Thomson let me rephrase, then. It won't even compile *with a real C++ compiler*. But even ignoring that, the `const&` version doesn't do the optimization.

Comment: not that GCC's "extensions" are "better"...

Comment: Move constructors and move assignment (C++11) provide a portable and reliable alternative to RVO.

Comment: While creating a reference to something does mean no copy takes place, that and copy elision are fundamentally different things. In copy elision, the source object is no longer created and the target object is used instead. When creating a reference to an object, the source object still exists, but there is no target object - we just make a reference to the source.

Comment: @user763305: Only for types that can be cheaply moved. Even then, doing nothing is a better optimisation than doing something.

Comment: From my experience: `C const& obj = f();` will have slightly worse performance than `C obj = f();` (although in most cases, the optimizer will remove the extra code).  It requires exactly the same number of copies, at least in practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can't (portably) use the temporary return value to initialise a non-const reference, so that's certainly not recommended.

Using it to initialise a const reference wouldn't have any effect on whether or not the copy/move of the return expression's value might be elided; although it would eliminate the notional copy/move used to initialise the variable from the returned value, whether or not that might have been elided. Of course, that's not the same as initialising a (non-reference) variable, since you can't modify it.

In practice, any compiler with a decent optimiser will elide copies and moves wherever it's allowed to. If you're not using a decent optimiser, then you can't expect decent performance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To manually make sure you don't get any redundant copies of objects, you need to do a bit more than what you did so far. Earlier I answered that it wouldn't be possible, but I was wrong. Also, your use of `const&` may disallow certain operations on the returned value that you do want to allow. Here's what I would do *if* you need to do the optimisations manually:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  S()
  { std::cout << "default constructor\n"; }
  S(const S &)
  { std::cout << "copy constructor\n"; }
  S(S &&)
  { std::cout << "move constructor\n"; }
  ~S()
  { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
};

S f() { return {}; }

int main() {
  auto&&s = f();
  std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

This prints "default constructor", followed by "main", and then "destructor". This is the output regardless of whether any copy elision takes place. Inside `main`, `s` is a named reference, so it is an lvalue, and it is not `const`-qualified. You can do everything with it that you otherwise could.

Given that it turns out fairly easy to avoid relying on copy elision in cases such as these, as long as you take care to pay attention to it from the start, it *may* be worth your efforts *if* you have to worry about other compilers not performing copy elision. Most compilers are capable of that, and there is a fair chance that if a compiler doesn't, it will have other, bigger, problems anyway, so there is a good argument for not worrying about it.

However, at the same time, copy elision is somewhat unreliable: even current optimising compilers do not *always* perform it, simply because there may be corner cases where copy elision would make sense, but is not permitted by the standard or not possible for that particular implementation. Forcing yourself to write code that doesn't rely on copy elision means you cannot get stuck in that situation.

That said, there are still some cases where copy elision can only realistically be eliminated by optimising compilers, so you may have no choice but to rely on it:

Suppose we add `void m();` to `S`'s definition. Suppose we now edit `f` to

```
S f() {
  S s;
  s.m();
  return s;
}
```

This is more difficult to rewrite into a form that guarantees no redundant copies. Yet at the same time, copies *are* unnecessary, as can easily be determined from the fact that with GCC (and probably other compilers too), by default, no copies are made.

My final conclusion is that it's probably not worth optimising for compilers that don't perform RVO, but it is worth thinking carefully about what exactly makes it work, and writing code in such a way that RVO remains not only possible, but becomes something a compiler is very likely to do.